Setting many-to-many navigation property to unmodified in EF6
I have an entity Order which has a many-to-many relationship with another entity Material. This relationship is represented by a collection navigation property Materials in the Order entity.
Since EF6 does not support filtered includes and I need to filter the loaded materials, I cannot use .Include() to load the materials. To work around this limitation, I have implemented a helper method that loads an Order and its associated Materials using separate queries. I then manually assign the result of the materials query to the Materials navigation property on the Order entity.
The issue with this approach is that if I don't use AsNoTracking(), EF6 will update the many-to-many mapping table when I call SaveChanges(). To avoid this, I want to effectively mark the Materials property as "unmodified". I want it to behave as if EF6 loaded the product with materials.
For primitive properties, this can be done using:
Context.Entry(product).Property(e => e.PropertyToKeepUnchanged).IsModified = false;

However, this approach doesn't work for collection navigation properties. How can I achieve the same effect for the collection properties?

What exactly are you trying to achieve? What's the reason for trying to set this navigation property to Unchanged? Show the bigger picture.

I think it's impossible to get this done with EF6. If you're going to tamper with entity state or even relationship states EF will immediately effectuate the changes in the actual Materials collections. I would use DTO classes for Order and Material and query the desired objects into those.

If you do not intend to modify the Order or the Material at all, consider loading them with .NoTracking(), maybe? Or are you touching the rest of the Order?
